# App description not updated in play store

Tags: android, google-play-console

I published my first android app for internal testing.Now I want to update the description and screenshots so I re-edited them in store listing page on play console and saved. But it's been 20 days I did it and it still doesn't show new screenshots whenever I check through account added for internal testing.
Do I need to create a new release to update the store description?

Comment: I have the same problem. I changed description and get updated on Web, but not get update on Play Store.